# Sum range of int's in List<int>

Tags: c#, list, sum

I reckon this will be quite trivial but I can't work out how to do it. I have a `List<int>` and I want to sum a range of the numbers.

Say my list is:

```
var list = new List<int>()
{
    1, 2, 3, 4
};
```

How would I get the sum of the first 3 objects? The result being 6. I tried using `Enumerable.Range` but couldn't get it to work, not sure if that's the best way of going about it.

Without doing:

```
int sum = list[0] + list[1] + list[2];
```

Comment: Please also see that if you include System.Linq you can use many other facilities with your collection : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) & [`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx):

```
var list = new List<int>()
{
    1, 2, 3, 4
};

// 1 + 2 + 3
int sum = list.Take(3).Sum(); // Result: 6
```

If you want to sum a range beginning elsewhere, you can use [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx):

```
var list = new List<int>()
{
    1, 2, 3, 4
};

// 3 + 4
int sum = list.Skip(2).Take(2).Sum(); // Result: 7
```

Or, reorder your list using [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) or [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx) and then sum:

```
var list = new List<int>()
{
    1, 2, 3, 4
};

// 3 + 4
int sum = list.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(2).Sum(); // Result: 7
```

As you can see, there are a number of ways to accomplish this task (or related tasks). See [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx), [`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx), [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx), [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) & [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx) documentation for further information.

Comment: Can we do the same with array also?

Answer (score 11):

Or just use Linq

```
int result = list.Sum();
```

To sum first three elements:

```
int result = list.GetRange(0,3).Sum();
```